# Prevent sleep while SSH session active

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sleep

I'm trying to prevent computer from going to sleep while there is an active SSH connection but just can't set it up.

Found a short description on how to do it but it doesn't work:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/521620/prevent-machine-from-sleeping-when-ssh-connections-are-on?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Since I'm using ubuntu 16.04 I have tried to move the script to /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ and it shows up in logs that script was executed and returned 1 before computer was suspended but it's not preventing it from going to sleep.

I have also tried using Caffeine but it will just crash every time I start it with following error:
/usr/bin/caffeine:25: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.

Any ideas why computer isn't reacting to script?

Comment: I also have the same issue. Try asking this over at askubuntu.com since this website is more for programming issues.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1172288/964557